# Confusion about usage of present tense vs past tense vs mixed

Tags: creative-writing, style, technique, research, tenses

I am quite new to writing so I hope my question makes any sense.

I'm trying to write a first draft of a story that has been haunting me for quite a while. Even though I'm fine with it to fail, I would like to try and finish the story and incoorporate good practise writing techniques where I can.

I have been enjoying the tale and filling up the details I had not yet thought of in the past.

However when researching dialog vs action scenes I keep falling in the rhythm of using past tense for (dialog) actions and present tense when people are talking about stuff.

Now I've read a few questions that looked similar: [this](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/23470/writing-dialogue-present-or-past-tense-said) and [this](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/3255/use-of-past-vs-present-tense-in-works-of-fiction).
But people keep giving conflicting answers which confuses me what to do.

I guess it is a matter of taste, but how can I be sure?

So my real question is not really about if I should do past or present tense but rather how I can be sure my writing does not become too 'weak'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tense of the narrative (that is, all the text surrounding direct speech) has nothing to do with the tense of the direct speech (the text within quotation marks). Someone in the past can speak of their present:

> Yesterday, when I stood here, I said: "I stand here now."

What you have to decide is whether you want to narrate your story in the past or present tense. There is no fundamental difference, and you can use either one, but you cannot mix them (in the narration).

The tenses in the speeches of your character will always be relative to their present, not yours.

Comment: So you are saying the tense of the dialogs are irrelevant. But all the narrative parts should be in the same tense (whichever one I choose)?

Comment: @TotumusMaximus The tense of the dialog is irrelevant to the tense of the narrative. And yes, all the narrative parts should be in the same tense.

Comment: I guess I will stick with my past tense then. I have tried fairly hard to see how the present tense would work out like in the example in my question. But it kept feeling unnatural to me.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus Past tense is the most common tense for fiction and a good choice. It is what most readers find more natural to read.

Comment: “And yes, all the narrative parts should be in the same tense.” — What if the narration starts in the past, but reaches the present? Wouldn't a switch to present tense at the end be natural then? Think e.g. of a prisoner telling the story of how he got into this situation. He would naturally end with his current situation. For me, the present tense would seem most natural for that, while the story so far would have been naturally in past tense (after all, it all happened in the past of him telling the story).

Comment: @celtschk There are about 36,812 special cases when it comes to tempus. I didn't want to overwhelm Totumus Maximus with them, as their problem seems to be much more basic than that. – I feel that an answer is best when it addresses the problem stated in the question, not when it expands to a general guide to all special problems related to a topic.

Comment: @Cloudchaser: You don't have to list all special cases in order to acknowledge they exist.

Answer (score 2):

> I guess it is a matter of taste, but how can I be sure?

Some stories can be told in either tense and it won't alter the feeling of them drastically, the difference can be quite subtle. Also, some writers hate writing in present tense while some find it's the only tense that comes naturally to them. So it can be a matter of taste.

However, sometimes a change in tense can have a big impact on a story.

For example, I wrote a literary fiction novel about two women who form a relationship over a long journey. I wrote that in past tense because I wanted it to be a lilting tale, told from the point of view of the older woman as she relayed the story of her experiences on that journey to the reader. A lot of time was spent inside the protagonist's head as she narrated her feelings (which you can do when looking back on an event in the past with hindsight).

Later, I wrote a fast-paced psychological thriller in present tense because I wanted a sense of immediacy. I wanted the reader to experience the thrill of the action scenes as if they were actually happening in the moment of reading. Handled well, it can create a closeness with your reader, the feeling that they're experiencing the journey while you're telling it. What I couldn't do was spend huge amounts of time inside my protagonist's head, because it's not realistic that we spend time in a sort of stasis while we mentally process an event happening in real time. But as it was a fast-paced novel, I didn't want the action to be slowed down by that anyway.

So, think about the bulk of your story. Every story is going to have its quiet moments and its thrilling moments, but think about the pace you want to create overall and rather than going on taste alone, think about what's best for your story. If you're slipping in and out without thinking, it sounds as if you're probably comfortable writing in either.

I don't know that you can be sure. You just have to make the best guess at what will work. Sometimes you only know with hindsight once the novel is done. But don't worry, you can always change it later. I've switched tense on a 130,000 word novel. It didn't take as long as I thought it would!!

Good luck!

Comment: My story is not really fast paced (i think) but has some action moments which i would like to have this sense of immediacy in. But present tense felt uncomfortable. But I do not want to have that effect of someone looking back on the story like you meant either. I have no idea what I truly want yet, for I have lots of challenges completing the story as it is.

Comment: You can still create immediacy with past tense, through the writing itself. Shorter sentences, for example, clipped, short words, coming right in close to the action and not wasting time on too much setting and exposition. Also, not showing the action through the character's eyes, helps to create a sense of immediacy.

Comment: For example (forgive me, it's a terrible example, but should illustrate the point) instead of writing 'John saw the zombie walk through the door, heard it's deep-throated grunt, and smelt the stench of rotting flesh.' Let the reader experience it for themselves. The zombie staggered through the door with a deep-throated snarl and the stench of rotting flesh filled John's nostrils.' By writing this way, even though it's in past tense, you bring the reader right up close to the action and create immediacy that way.

Comment: Anne Lamott says that every writer should allow themselves to write shitty first drafts. Every writer writes shitty first drafts and it's okay because they lead to slightly less-shitty second drafts and maybe a passable third. So, my advice would be, just tell your story to the page as if you are making it up as you go along for a captive listener who can't wait to hear the next word out of your lips. Just get it down. Don't worry about tense, POV, etc etc. These can all be ironed out in your second draft once you can see the story as a whole.

Comment: The one thing I would recommend you do though is, spend a lot of time getting to know your characters before you start writing. You need to know these people as well as you know yourself. Write histories and back stories for them, interview them and ask them questions, until you know exactly who they are and exactly how they will respond in any given situation. -

Comment: Because, in my experience, it's my harder to round out a character once the story is down and they've already committed to their actions and dialogue. Maybe some writers can do that, but I find it really difficult. But once you know who they are, start writing their story and allow yourself the freedom of that shitty first draft.

Comment: This lady on YouTube is talking about Scrivener (writing software which I use personally and highly recommend but that's very complex). However, her video will give you some excellent insights into pre-writing, what she does before she even starts writing. And you'll see that most of what she does is character development. It may help, some great tips there:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-x1aN7Rpl4&index=7&list=WL&t=0s

Comment: Let's first say I appreciate your answer and comments. They are helpful. I am prepared to write a shitty first draft but I also want to know why it is shitty as I write it and if I can do better as I am writing the story. I have been trying to start this for a few years now but never had this much resolve to start... and finish hopefully. I will take a look at the YouTube when I got some leftover time.

Comment: TM, your dedication to this craft and your work is admirable. But writing a novel is hard hard hard. Don't make it harder for yourself. You have to find your own path, and there’s nothing inherently wrong with what you’re hoping to achieve, it's the path I took with my first novel. I pored over every line, rewrote the first chapter dozens of times, fought to make it the best it could be every step of the way and refused to let anyone read it until I'd polished it red-raw. It took three years. And it failed. Three years of work and now it sits on my desk as a reminder.

Comment: My second novel, I wrote in ten weeks. I just wrote it. No revisions, no poring, just spilling words onto the page as if a middle aged woman (my audience) was sitting next to me hanging on every word. Then, without even redrafting once, I sent it straight out to a team of beta-readers I trust with my life. They knew it was my shitty first draft and they tore it apart. I used all that great and brutal feedback to help me figure out why it was shitty and then I did better. Armed with their intelligent insights I wrote a much better second draft and an even better third.

Comment: Did it fail because I allowed myself a shitty first draft? On the contrary, the response I got to that novel was overwhelming. Like you, I’m still finding my way in this craft, I’m on my third novel now and I’ll definitely write a shitty first draft when I’ve finished plotting it. There are very experienced writers out there who can write in one draft and get it perfect first time, but I’d say the majority write shitty first drafts.

Comment: In my experience, you’re usually too close to your own work to see why it’s shitty. You need qualified, trusted readers to do that for you. So just dive in and write it. Devour books on the craft of writing. Devour books in your genre and analyse how they achieved success. If you want to traditionally publish, look at what else is out there, what agents and publishers are looking for and what sells. Know your audience. Know your market. But the craft will come as you write. It won’t if you don’t. Be brave! Just go for it! The very best of luck to you.

Comment: Thank you :) my next challenge (after writing all this stuff in my head) is to find some beta-readers I can trust. I don't know if I can trust them with my life but some nice brutal critisism sounds good. I expect to need it badly. I am in no real rush to write. At this moment I write like a chapter of 3-5k words in a week. And I am happy because I have finally started this challenge I had always wanted to take.

Comment: Yes, trusted readers are essential. Do not ask family and friends for two reasons: 1. They (hopefully) like you too much to tell you the truth. 2. If they aren't educated in the craft of writing, they will not be able to fully articulate what isn't working, why, and how you might go about fixing it. Writers' groups, writing classes and writing societies are all good places to find fellow writers and start a group if there isn't one local to you. And 3-5K a week is FANTASTIC! That's a novel in 4-7 months. Brilliant! Come back on here and let me know how you get on.